# Unable to upload file from Files application

Tags: iphone, ios, file-sharing, dropbox, google-apps

When I go to App Library -> Productivity & Finance -> Files on my iPhone 12 Pro Max (iOS 14.8) I have an Exports folder with a number of [*.glb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF) files in it. I click on one, click on the upload icon at the bottom left and select (Google) Drive. The progress bar moves forward but then I get an error:

> Some items failed to upload to Drive and could not be shared. Please try again.

Underneath the filename it says "*No internet connection*".

Dropbox is even more useless.  The Post button is disabled unless I add my own email address to the To section. When I do so I can click on Post but then the window closes with no error message at all.

I don't understand. Sure, I don't have a SIM card in the phone, but I do have WiFi enabled and I was able to pull up the most recent version of cnn.com just now and even install an app.

I tried to upload an image from the Photos application and was unable to do so via (Google) Drive (the progress bar progressed but nothing new is showing up in drive.google.com on my computer) BUT it did work via Dropbox.

Good on Dropbox for letting me upload images but why can't I upload *.glb files?

edit: I can AirDrop the files to my MacBook but I'd really rather not. I want to share them with a third party and I'd much rather do so in one step (uploading straight to Google Drive or Dropbox) instead of AirDrop'ing them to my MacBook and then uploading them to Google Drive or Dropbox from my MacBook. The former is one step, the latter is two steps.

Comment: Roughly how large is one file? As all the files downloaded fully to your iOS or still in another cloud for this cloud to cloud transfer?

Comment: @bmike - the biggest one is 32MB, the smallest one is 4MB. The one I was trying to upload via DropBox / Drive was 25MB (I only tried it with the one file). All the files are fully downloaded to my iOS (I created them on my iPhone with poly.cam and am trying to upload them from my iPhone to the cloud)

Comment: Excellent, that will help, but Dropbox tends to throttle uploads severely in my experience. Especially in marginal cellular or wifi situations exacerbating packet loss or retries. Did you know your Mac can enable iCloud caching to accelerate these sync between all devices and the cloud? Enabling that might just get them all on your Mac without airdrop at local lan speeds.

Comment: This issue happened to me, but only when I was uploading to Drive via the "Share" interface (not only in the Files app, but also the Goodnotes app). Uploading directly via the Google Drive app worked.